# JavaScript merge arrays from two different functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Hey I want to merge those two arrays and use it as one array.**

Assigning variables:

```
var worldData = [];
var europeData = [];
var allData = [];
```

Code to fetch data from Data Source 1:

```
fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data_world) => getWorldData(data_world));
```

First function:

```
const getAllData = (data_world) => {
  worldData = [
    data_world.todayCases,
    data_world.todayRecovered,
    data_world.todayDeath
  ];
  
  return worldData;
};
```

Code to fetch data from Data Source 2:

```
fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents/Europe?strict=true')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data_eu) => getEuropeData(data_eu));
```

Second function:

```
const getEuropeData = (data_eu) => {
  europeData = [
    data_eu.todayCases,
    data_eu.todayRecovered,
    data_eu.todayDeath
  ];
  
  return europeData;
};
```

Merging arrays (didn't work):

```
allData = [...worldData, ...europeData]
allData = worldData.concat(europeData)
```

**I can't put arrays outside these functions because i'm fetching data from two different sources and I want to store all data inside one array.**

Comment: could you make your problem more clear?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Right I was going to say the same thing, Specifically, what do you mean by stating

**"I need arrays inside those functions so putting arrays outside functions is not a solution."** 

Please make this as clear as possible.

Comment: why do you need two functions to do the same task?

Comment: do you have some data and wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah, I have to different data sources and I need to merge results into one array.

Comment: @Naren Almost. I'm fetching data from two different sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer but forgot to post there.

My solution:

```js
let arr = [];

fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    arr.push(
      Object.values(data)[2],
      Object.values(data)[6]
    );
    return arr;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = tempArray1.concat(tempArray2);
```

According to a quick google search.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you not get the result you're expecting? Is it possible the problem is in the code where you do something to the merged array?

Comment: Array is empty. I think arrays are not returned at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the result and push the object top the array.

The `setTimeout` is to prevent to show an empty array.

```js
const
    result = [],
    addToResult = ({ todayCases, todayRecovered, todayDeaths }) => {
        result.push({ todayCases, todayRecovered, todayDeaths });
    };


fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(addToResult);

fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents/Europe?strict=true')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(addToResult);

setTimeout(() => console.log(result), 1000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```